# How can I connect to a SSH tunnel using PUTTY or another client, with the information available through SSH command?

Tags: ssh, putty

I am trying to establish a connection in SSH, to a remotehost...

I am having the following information from my company(example, not real data)...

ssh -p 1234 -L 4321:126.4.12.3:4423 user3@12.42.123.323 -N

They asked me to connect using Linux command, in their environment...

I am trying to connect with the details through my PUTTY terminal from my personal computer...

Which data to give in which place for PUTTY connection?

Thanks,

Mani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `putty` as front end, use Plink in command line :

```
plink.exe -P 1234 -L 4321 126.4.12.3:4423 user3@12.42.123.323 -N
```

See http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html and to download it : http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/plink.exe

Comment: plink, does it work on windows??? Nothing happens when I double click on the exe...

Comment: As you can see, it's a `*.exe` file, so yes, it's for windows. Download the executable, open a windows terminal `cmd`, type `chdir <PATH/TO/EXE/DIR>` and my command line.

Comment: unknown option -p, i am getting as the message, when i give the command...

Comment: Use `-P` instead. See doc : http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.62/htmldoc/Chapter7.html#plink Thanks to upvote and accept response if it's useful for you ;)

Comment: yeah, i have accepted that as the answer...upvote requires 15 reputation...i can't rite now...!:) cheers!